# Android:Unable to receive data from Service to Activity through Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity and and a service. I am running my service in background in a time interval through AlaramManager. What I want is to receive periodically data from the service inside activity. For this I'm using broadcastreceiver, but it does not showing any data.

In my service I'm using this method for sending data:

```
        private final void sendServiceActiveBroadcast(final boolean pActivate) {
        final Intent _intent = new Intent();
        _intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        _intent.addCategory("com.monday.worker_android.android.CATEGORY");
        _intent.putExtra("isactive", pActivate);

        NewService.this.sendBroadcast(_intent);
    }
```

And use it inside an AsyncTask class like:

```
      @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("Post Execute", "Executed");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        float[] arr = new float[30];
        if (round(distance(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, lati, longi)) < 200) {
        Log.d("OnPostExecute", "In");
        sendServiceActiveBroadcast(true);
       }
  }
```

And try to receive this in my activity like:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean value = intent.getBooleanExtra("isactive", false);
        if (value == true) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " not received",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};
```

I resister it in my onResume() and unresister it in my onPause() like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(NewService.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);     
    super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

I just check some tutorials and code it. My application is working fine with service and also it excutes the onPostExecute() perfectly. But it does't show any broadcast data.

Can any one please suggest me how to receive periodically data from service and why I fail to receive data here and about my mistakes.

**Thank You**

Comment: What do you need CATEGORY for?

Comment: Here I define all  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter().is there anything to add?

Comment: @Carnal: I just saw some tutorials and add define these.Is there any suggestions for me that how to do this plz.

Comment: remove the addCategory!

Comment: Thanks Carnal.After remove the CATEGORY it works fine. Can you please tell me why CATEGORY makes problem here.Why this silly mistake did such a big problem for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addCategory
```

is the problem in your code. Because, in your activity you didn't set the `category` attribute, so the reference can not be found. Also, without having the category you can send this to multiple receivers at different locations with `action` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Carnal. Can you give me some good links which will help me to clear in Broadcastreceiver.

Comment: Shows you how to create a custom receiver class, and register it in Manifest. So you have two options.